# Best way to extern chrome extensions API, to work with Closure compiler Advanced Optimization?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-closure-compiler

Is there an easy way to use advanced optimization on my Chrome extension's code?

It uses chrome API, and Advanced Optimization doesn't recongnize its keywords.  Is there a file or something that externs all chrome API?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Whenever you're in need of an externs file, take a look at the [contrib/externs](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/tree/master/contrib/externs) directory of the closure-compiler repository. The externs for Chrome extensions is found at [contrib/externs/chrome_extensions.js](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/contrib/externs/chrome_extensions.js), and can be used as follows:

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
// @externs_url https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/closure-compiler/master/contrib/externs/chrome_extensions.js
// ==/ClosureCompiler==

// Your code here.
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I was looking for!  I knew that existed, but was unable to find it!

Comment: Hm, maybe this is outdates, I still see `variable chrome is undeclared`

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich did you manage to solve this? I'm running into the same issue: `chrome_extensions.js:224: ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable chrome is undeclared`

Comment: alright, adding a dummy variable solves the issue: `var chrome;` I added it at the top of the extern file (I'm using the CLI version of the compiler)

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich chrome externs ,https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/contrib/externs/chrome.js